# Questions in the process of finding the first principal component vector.

Tags: linear-algebra

The process of finding the first principal component, $\mathbf{w}_{(1)}$, is explained in [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Details).
However, I do not understand why the following two equations are equivalent.
$$
\underset{\lVert\mathbf{w}\rVert=1}{\operatorname{arg\,max}}\left\{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}\right\} = \operatorname{arg\,max}\left\{\frac{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}}{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}}\right\}
$$
The site says it is because $\mathbf{w}$ is a unit vector.
Is there a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The norm of $\mathbf{w}$ can be written as $\sqrt{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}}$. So, the expression $\frac{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}}{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}}$ can be rewritten as $\frac{\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}}{||\mathbf{w}||^2}=\frac{\mathbf{w}^T}{||\mathbf{w}||}X^TX\frac{\mathbf{w}}{||\mathbf{w}||}$ which is of the form on the left hand side.

Comment: If so, do I have to determine the result as a $\frac{\mathbf{w}}{\lVert\mathbf{w}\rVert}$ in the right problem?

Comment: What I did shows that the two sides are equivalent since the sets will contain the same elements. If you have an element of the set on the left given by some $\mathbf{w}$, then it will be an element of the set on the right. And if you have an element of the set on the right given by some $\mathbf{w}$, then it is also an element of the set on the left given by $\frac{\mathbf{w}}{||\mathbf{w}||}$. So you are taking the arg of the max of the same set in the end.